# Responsive design - 2 column down to one column

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have 2 divs floated left so they will appear inline

```
<div class==".container" style="width: 100%">
    <div class="leftColumn" style="width: 50%; float:left">
        test
    </div>

    <div class="rightColumn" style="width: 50%; float:left">
        test
    </div>
</div>
```

When the screen falls below 400px I want the divs to appear underneath each other
My current media query

```
@media(max-width: 400)
{
    .leftColumn{background-color: Red; float: none}
    .rightColumn{background-color: Blue; float: right} 
}
```

Thanks to anyone who can help

Comment: What's your problem? Why isn't your current solution not working. Also, you have a typo; `class==".container"` is invalid, which may be why things aren't working. It should be `class="container"`.

Comment: Thanks but the problem persists. The divs still appear inline.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have the same effect by

```css
@media(max-width: 400) {
   .leftColumn, .rightColumn{width:100%;} 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.

I had inline styling on the divs

```
<div class="leftColumn" style="width: 50%; float:left">
    test
</div>
```

When i removed it, it all worked.

Comment: Another reason to stay away from inline styling. Not surprising, as inline styles receive a much higher priority than regular CSS styles.

Comment: Wesley, if this resolves your question, you should pick your own answer as the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

Yep, inline styling was buggering it up, plus you weren't defining your media queries 100% correctly, needed the px:

http://jsfiddle.net/XmqNy/